# EF Core App - How do I script for installation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I've got a an EF Core Application (using WPF, C#) that I can build and run just fine as a developer.  I have no problems editing my data model, creating migrations and updating the database from Package Manager Console.  But now I'm trying to write an installer (evaluating various install tools) and I'm wondering what to do at installation time.

All the EF Core documentation I can find seems to address database creation purely from a developer's perspective.  But I can't exactly have a user run package-manager console on my source code.  Yet once my app is installed, the database needs to exist.  I don't know how best to use the outputs that EF Core gives me to create the database at install time.  What is the best practice?

For example, in my project I see that "Migrations" folder, that EF Core created for me when I ran the `add-migration` command from PM Console.  It has a class derived from "Migration" with the "Up" method that creates tables in C#.

```
public partial class init : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AnalysisTypes",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Key = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Show = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AnalysisTypes", x => x.Key);
            });

        ...etc ... etc... etc...
```

It *seems* as if it would be ideal to create my database.  Like maybe I should somehow extract this Migration-derived class into a separate console app to be run at install time to create the database. Is this something that is typically done?

Alternately, if I run the `script-migration -idempotent` command from PM Console, I get a SQL script that creates the tables I need.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );
END;

GO

CREATE TABLE [AnalysisTypes] (
    [Key] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Show] bit NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AnalysisTypes] PRIMARY KEY ([Key])
);

GO

... etc ... etc... etc...
```

But that script ***only*** creates tables.  It has no provision to connect to the database or see if it exists and create it if it does not.  I need a smarter script to

- Connect to the right sql server
- Check to see if the database exists
- Create it if it does not.
- Ensure its schema is up to date.

So am I supposed to take this script-migration-generated script and wrap it in some larger one that does all of that work for me?  Is there some command that will do all that?

I assume this is a solved problem in the EF Core world.  I'm just looking for what is a best practice.  Can anyone give me any guidance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the database created, you can set the Database initializer to migrate to the newest version by setting calling [SetInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/index#automatically-upgrading-on-application-startup-migratedatabasetolatestversion-initializer).

```
Database.SetInitializer<ObjectContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ObjectContext, Configuration>());
```

**From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818489.aspx**

> If you were to compile the project and give it to another developer
>   who hasn’t migrated her own development database, the initializer
>   would trigger the app to look for a migration. The migration will be
>   found because it’s in the project. The initializer will check the
>   database’s migration history table and update the database schema, if
>   necessary.
>
> Considering this in production, not development, the migration class
>   will be compiled into your assembly and deployed as part of the
>   application. When the application is run, it will respond to a
>   MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion setting (in the appropriate place in
>   your application) and update the database schema accordingly.

You can read more about Migrations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/index#getting-a-sql-script).

EDIT

**For EF Core:**
**From:** http://flores.eken.nl/ef-core-equivalent-of-migratedatabasetolatestversion/

> And now the important part. Of course you want your program to run the
>   migration (and subsequent ones) automatically upon application
>   startup. In the EF 6.x days this could be done by using the
>   MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer.
>
> This changed in EF core. Now you will have to use:

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Ok, and how does that solve his "create the database on a server you do not know yet and likely have no permission to do that"?

Comment: It seems like he is manually creating the database and permissions.  I believe the OP is asking how to run the migration from code at startup.

Comment: Yes, Michael, that is precisely what I'm asking.  (Or rather at install time but I don't think that's an important distinction)

Comment: I see that in Entity Framework but no in EFCore.  However I do see something that looks similar. It looks like could call DbContext.Database.Migrate().  Is that the "correct" way to ensure all migrations are applied?

Comment: Hi Joe, yes, that's correct.  my apologies, I overlooked that this is for EF Core.  My latest edit should provide you with additional context.

Comment: Perfect.  Two lines of code.  Much easier than trying to manually apply some sort of database script.  Much appreciated